# Excel - refer to an empty cell in CONCATENATE function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In an Excel spreadsheet, Let's say a certain bonus is displayed (numerical value) if all three cells of the range match the criteria, the "smaller bonus" values are displayed when only two of the three cells match the criteria.

I have created the bonus list on separate sheet called 'bonuses', with the additional helper column concatenating three cells values and tried the following formula:

=INDEX(bonuses!E:E,MATCH(CONCATENATE(W3,X3,Y3),bonuses!D:D,0))

The formula works perfectly well when all three numbers are needed to receive the bonus, but there is another set of "smaller bonuses" issued on two out of three numbers to be a match. Since the third cell is never empty, above formula cannot find the concatenated value of the two-digit values. Is there a way to modify the formula to encompass the small bonuses too? Perhaps I need to find a way to refer to the third cell as to an empty cell? Could someone advise, please?

Comment: So sometimes you want to match based on only `concatenate(W3,X3)`, and sometimes on `concatenate(W3,X3,Y3)`? How do you know when to only use the two cells? Perhaps some sample data with expected output will help.

Comment: Is it always W3 & X3 that will match on the "smaller bonuses" or is it simply 2 out of 3 in any combination?

Comment: @Kyle - Actually They need to be from a specific range, although there are 12 ranges. If all three values are from the same range the bonus kicks in, if only two of the three numbers match the criteria, the "small bonus" kicks in.

Comment: @Mark - I could go with either, since I have a helper column where with a certain array formula, the criteria-matching pair are always in W3 and X3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's long but it appears to work:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Bonuses!E:E,MATCH(TRIM(W3)&TRIM(X3)&TRIM(Y3),Bonuses!D:D,0))),0,INDEX(Bonuses!E:E,MATCH(TRIM(W3)&TRIM(X3)&TRIM(Y3),Bonuses!D:D,0)))
```

It will check for a bonus with 3 values. If found it will return the bonus. If NOT found, it will check for a 2 value bonus. If still not found, it returns zero.  The 2 values bonus can be either W & Y or X & Y, since you stated that the 3rd column will always be populated.

This Formula assumes you have, in your bonus table, the possible 2 value bonuses listed in Column D of the Bonuses worksheet. It also assumes that the values are text.  The Trim (and also Concatenate) returns a text value.

Comment: It worked, and thanks for posting the answer, although I pursued another path, still appreciate you time and effort. Sorry for being late with the response - weekend.